# Regarding Python list output

Tags: python, list

Hi could someone please tell me why this code prints out the last item ("Phoebe Buffay") on the list and not the whole list.

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []

for name in names:
  usernames = name.replace(" ","_")

print(usernames)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need the `append` function.

Comment: Put the print inside the loop--indent it

Comment: @Chinedu FYI, u can also ``["_".join(x.split()) for x in ["Joey Tribbiani"]]``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the value of `usernames` each time and not appending to the list as you probably want:

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []

for name in names:
  usernames.append(name.replace(" ","_"))

print(usernames)
```

This outputs what you expect:

```
['Joey_Tribbiani', 'Monica_Geller', 'Chandler_Bing', 'Phoebe_Buffay']
```

In your code, you're not using the original `usernames` list to keep any data, instead you're replacing what `usernames` is referring to for each iteration of the for loop - and after the for loop is finished, that's the last element in your original list.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `append()`:

```
for name in names:
    usernames.append(name.replace(" ","_"))
```

Otherwise, you're overwriting `usernames` in each iteration and it is a string, not a list anymore. More `Pythonic` would be to use a list comprehension altogether:

```
usernames = [name.replace(" ", "_") for name in names]
```